# Can ember-routemanager add states dynamically on load?

Tags: url-routing, ember.js

I have a route manager defined like in the following code.

```
App.routeManager = Ember.RouteManager.create();
```

I don't want to statically add viewstate to the manager; I want to determine what states there are on load depends on data. How can I do that? I'm looking for something like the following code.

```
foreach(item in itemArray){
      App.routeManager.states.add(Ember.ViewState.create(
             route: 'item.route'
      ));
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't tried that before, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Have you tried it yet? What happened?

Comment: i tried the exact syntax i posted and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically gave yourself the answer, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/xNnTP/:

```js
App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
    enableLogging: true,
    initialState: 'firstState',
    firstState: Ember.State.create({
        myEvent: function(manager) {
            manager.goToState('addedState');
        }
    })
});

Ember.run.later(function() {
    Ember.setPath(App.stateManager, 'states.addedState', Ember.State.create({
        enter: function() {
            this._super();
            console.log('hello dynamic world');
        }
    }));
    App.stateManager.send('myEvent');
}, 10);​
```